# I am not getting Account custom field value to pass in window.location?

Tags: custom-button, detail-page

Please help me with the code, where i am going wrong , on it

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/33.0/connection.js")}
var id="{!Account.Id}";
alert("Account id" +id);
if(id!=null){
alert('id is not null');
var sid="{!Account.custom_external_Id__c}";
**alert(sid+"sid is not null"); - in this line - i am getting sid=# error**
window.location="http://xxx.com/testing/test/"+sid+";
}
else
alert('some errors');
window.location.href='/'+id;
```

Comment: Fyi there is a spurious `+"` on the end of the line that sets the window location.

Comment: var sid='{!JSENCODE(Account.custom_External_Id__c)}'; this worked to me . Thanks for the reply @keith C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/33.0/connection.js")}
var id="{!Account.Id}";
alert("Account id" +id);
if(id!=null){
    alert('id is not null');
    var sid='{!JSENCODE(Account.custom_External_Id__c)}';
    alert(sid+"sid is not null");
}
```

JSENCODE works to me.

When I used this line `var sid="{!Account.custom_external_Id__c}"` if the external ID contained a quote character JavaScript would interpret that as the end of the `sid` string and so the remaining text would result in an error.

Using `var sid='{!JSENCODE(Account.custom_External_Id__c)}'` any embedded quotes (or other character that might produce similar problems) are escaped by preceding them with a backslash so ensuring that JavaScript treats the external ID as a single string.

Comment: If you explained what the problem was and why this is the works the answer would be more valuable.

Comment: I added in a bit more detail and +1.